# How to pass file location as a parameter in testng.xml

Tags: maven, testng, parameter-passing, pom.xml, testng-eclipse

I need to pass file location as parameter in testng.xml. I'm working on a framework which accepts the location of excel file (Data driven) as parameter in testng.xml. Below is a sample of testng.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<parameter name="Excel" value="C:\Users\workspace\PracticeProjects\MavenSample\src\test\resources\excel\hello.xlsx"></parameter>
  <test name="Test">
  <classes>
  <class name="com.abc.props.SampleTest11"></class>
  </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Since the work space location would differ for different users, I would like to understand if there is a way to dynamically identify the value instead of hard-coding. If the base path location or root directory of project is identified, the remaining src\test\resources\excel\hello.xlsx would remain constant. Looking for help on how to do that.

The project is a Maven project and if I can somehow identify the base directory of project in pom.xml and pass it as value to testng.xml, that would also solve my purpose.

I understand there is a way to pass the value through command line but am looking for the above mentioned approaches.

Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: Your excel file will be same in Project Directory ?

Comment: @IshitaShah : If the Project is getting downloaded in different machine then the project directory will change . so we need to change the parameter path

Answer (score 0):

You can use Below code to access file with its location :

```
// give you current execution direcory 
String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String fileName = currentDir+File.separator+"src"+File.separator+"test"+File.separator
+"resources"+File.separator+"excel"+File.separator+"hello.xlsx"

// File.separator this will works for ubuntu,windows and Mac.
```